# ASP.NET DropDownList with DataSource doesn't select any item

Tags: c#, asp.net, data-binding

I'm using a `DropDownList` with a data source which successfully populates the list. However, I want one of the items to be selected, namely the one where the value matches the path and query of the current request.

```
ddlTopics.DataSource = pdc;
ddlTopics.DataBind();
foreach (ListItem item in ddlTopics.Items)
{
    item.Selected = item.Value.Equals(this.Page.Request.Url.PathAndQuery);
}
```

Using the debugger in Visual Studio 2008 reveals that `item.Selected` becomes true exactly once in the loop, but the rendered `select` has no `option` that is selected.

Any ideas?

Comment: Could you please post the html rendered in the browser ? I encountered some thing similar to this previously, that would be helpful. Thanks

Comment: @Mahesh Velaga: I'm sorry, I can't. It's not at all interesting though, just a standard `select` with a bunch of `option` children.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use

```
ddlTopics.SelectedValue = this.Page.Request.Url.PathAndQuery;

    // Summary:
    //     Gets the value of the selected item in the list control, or selects the item
    //     in the list control that contains the specified value.
```

Answer (score 2):

You can try this:

```
ddlTopics.SelectedIndex = ddlTopics.Items.IndexOf(ddlTopics.Items.FindByValue(this.Page.Request.Url.PathAndQuery));
```

Comment: Very, very neat. Thank you! EDIT: Saw that Sorpigal had an even more superior solution, so I accepted her/his instead.

Comment: This is essentially what setting .SelectedValue does, except that .SelectedValue does more error checking.

Comment: The main reason I use SelectedIndex is because SelectedValue throws an ArgumentOutOfRange exception when the value is not found. SelectedIndex does nothing when the index is not found.

Comment: More precisely SelectedIndex will call ClearSelection() when the index is not found. I consider throwing an exception to be better (I'd rather handle an exception than have non-obvious behavior) but it depends on your personal preference.

Answer (score 0):

Set the`ddlTopics.SelectedIndex` property to the index of the item you wanted selected.

Answer (score 0):

I've always used

```
ddlTopics.SelectedIndex
```

to indicate that a row is selected, rather than assigning to the row individually.

Answer (score 0):

This is how I do it...

```
  foreach (var itm in cboOffice.Items) {
        if (itm.Value == Session("office")) {
            itm.Selected = true;
            break; //OR EXIT FOR
        }
    }
```